# botframework mention conversation id in webchat

Tags: node.js, botframework

How do we mention the conversation `id` in the `botframework webchat` instead of it being randomly generated? We can currently mention the `userid` and `username` for the `webchat` but could not have the conversation `id` mentioned.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "mention the conversation" id.  Can you clarify?

Comment: when we embed the webchat, we are able to pass in the userId and userName as params. I was wondering if there is any option for us to manually set the conversation Id in the session.message.address so that we can push messages to webchat.

Answer (score 1):

For more information on this subject, check out the guide: [Send proactive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-proactive-messages).

> To be able to send an ad hoc message to a user, the bot must first collect and save information about the user from the current conversation. The address property of the message includes all of the information that the bot will need to send an ad hoc message to the user later.

```
bot.dialog('/', function(session, args) {
    var savedAddress = session.message.address;

     // (Save this information somewhere that it can be accessed later, such as in a database.)

    var message = 'Hello user, good to meet you! I now know your address and can send you notifications in the future.';
    session.send(message);
});
```

> After the bot has collected information about the user, it can send an ad hoc proactive message to the user at any time. To do so, it simply retrieves the user data that it stored previously, constructs the message, and sends it.

```
function sendProactiveMessage(address) {
    var msg = new builder.Message().address(address);
    msg.text('Hello, this is a notification');
    msg.textLocale('en-US');
    bot.send(msg);
}
```

Comment: Actually the question is about => UserA is going on the WebChat and then reload the page. When reloading the page the user is still the same (cookie), but the Conversation.Id is different. In that case the builder.Message().address(address) is not working. The address identical except for the conversation id.